# AppStore requests iOS 11.0 when deployment target is set on iOS 10.0

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, ios11

I just released a new app on the AppStore and something strange is happening. When people try to download it, they are requested to upgrade to iOS 11.0 or above if they haven't done so already.

My **deployment target in Xcode (9) is set to iOS 10.0** and I do not use any new features that would be iOS 11 only. It's a very simple app that just fetches data from Firebase and displays them in tableViews ... nothing fancy.

Any idea why this might be happening? I don't really see where I made a mistake here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you get any warnings at all when building your project?

Comment: @jaga nope no warnings whatsoever, I had to kill Xcode, delete Derived Data folder, re-archive the build and push an update to fix the problem. Very strange.